# Is there any Alternative of Dictionary<Key, Value> with non contiguous memory allocation in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, data-structures, collections, sortedlist

Using Dictionary<Key, Value> causing issues in memory allowing ( error Failed to allocate memory) in the application So is there any alternative which is allocate memory in non contiguous form.

I tried with sortedList<Key, Value> collection but doesn’t work out

Comment: How many entries do you store in the dictionary? And what is the type of the keys and the values?

Comment: You could give this a try: [Developer-Alexander/LargeCollections](https://github.com/Developer-Alexander/LargeCollections)

Comment: Please add more details. Describe what you are doing, add a code snippet showing your use case and provide some information about the error you are getting (include the full stack trace and the error message if possible).

Answer (score -2):

Memory allocation will be based on the objects you add to the dictionary (or HashSet or SortedList, or any kind of list).

If you want to keep fixed sized of items in your dictionary, you can pass the **capacity** for the dictionary when instantiating it.
Or you can use `Stack<TItem>` with capacity so you can push/pop.